# Anyone planning to attend the Ohio Valley User Group (December 5th)?

Tags: discussion

I'm talking at a User Group meeting next week in Columbus (details [here](http://www.sdl.com/events/wcm/tridiondayOhio2013.html)), if anyone is showing up and feels like grabbing a drink or just general chatting on Tridion, weather, and upvotes, let me know - I'll get to Columbus the night before and there's a bar stool at the Westin with my name on it.

Unfortunately I'll need to fly out right after the event on Thursday, so drinks *after* the meeting will not be possible for me.

Comment: I'll be in town the week after for some functional workshops so any recaps appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In case you're looking at the agenda and the speakers, I unfortunately won't be there. But Nuno has a very good presentation, so you should definitely go!